# Get a spans innerHTML inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, innerhtml

Hi I've been looking around now for a few days and I seriously can't find anything, what I want is to call a span inside a div and get the spans innerHTMTL.
Now the code looks like this:

The span looks like this:

```
function createTimer() {
        return document.createElement("span");
    }
```

And this span is inside of this div as you can see:

```
var Stopwatch = {
init: function(elem, options) {

    var timer = createTimer(),
    startButton = createButton("start", start),
    stopButton = createButton("stop", stop),
    resetButton = createButton("reset", reset),
    offset,
    clock,
    interval;

    options = options || {};
    options.delay = options.delay || 1;

    elem.appendChild(timer);
    elem.appendChild(startButton);
    elem.appendChild(stopButton);
    elem.appendChild(resetButton);

    reset();

    function createTimer() {
        return document.createElement("span");
    }
```

I have tried to call this using `Stopwatch.span.innerHTML`, `.stopwatch span.innerHTML` and many other different ways. You can call it in css using this `.stopwatch span` but here is the problem I need to calll it in a button or something like this `<button id="first" onclick=".stopwatch span.innerHTML;"></button>`.
But it dosent work ! If there's any questions just ask and thanks in advance ! :)

**UPDATE:** Here is a messy JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dzcv9847/

Comment: Can u make [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Yeah sure give me a minute

Comment: @phillip100 I have just updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to dig into the function and change `var timer = createTimer(),` to `this.timer = createTimer();` to be able use something like `Stopwatch.timer.innerHTML;` however the way the timer is created now, the object is not accessible as it is.

This works without changes:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("basic");
  for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    Stopwatch.init(elems[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById("first").onclick=function() {
    var val = document.querySelector('.stopwatch > span').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("lap").innerHTML=val;
  }  
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/n7emsqzn/)

---

UPDATE: A little more elegant:

```
    lapButton = createButton("lap", lap),
    lapSpan = createTimer(),
    ...
    function lap() {
      lapSpan.innerHTML=timer.innerHTML;
    }

    function reset() {
        clock = 0;
        render(0);
        lap();
    }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5v4cx3om/)

Comment: I suggest the first approach, the caller has less knowledge about the internal structure of StopWatch. The third one I would surely stay away from because it assumes  a single instance per page.

Comment: I've tried all three, in the first one the timer dissipears , the second one it happends nothing, and in the third one the timer dissipears again

Comment: It works but now I've hitted another problem,, I have an animation and the timer starts when the animation has completed. But now instead I can't call the function the starts the timer, here's a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n7emsqzn/7/. And the console says: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", and because of this it won't lap the time even if I start the timer manully

Comment: Move the last } before your animation to AFTER the animation I.e. Inside the window.onliad

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally insert the button inside `.basic` div element (don't use `id`, use class instead):

```
<div class="basic stopwatch">
    <button class="get-timer" >Get milliseconds and display under this button onclick:</button>
    <div class=output></div>
</div>
```

And then:

**[EDIT]** (removed alert as pointed out *@mplungjan*)

```
var Stopwatch = {
    init: function(elem, options) {

        // ...
        var getTimerBtn = elem.getElementsByClassName("get-timer")[0];
        var outputElem =  elem.getElementsByClassName("output")[0];
        getTimerBtn.onclick = function(){
            outputElem.innerText = timer.innerText;
        }
        // ...

    }
}
```

That way, you can have multiple `timer` instances (see demo), without repeating the code for each button separately.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5cuno2se/)

Comment: @mplungjan , have look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/5cuno2se/ . That way, you can have multiple timer instances, without repeating the code for each button and timer.

Comment: @mplungjan , use loops **only** when necessary. Having the button with `id` outside main element, you need for separate code to connect both elements.

Comment: This is a new creation (using my scenario BTW, with button and output moved inside elem.). Going this way I could make it **a way** faster and shorter... (well... my code is still faster and shorter :) )

Comment: Granted I used your idea, but my implementation, including the HTML is  shorter and less complex than your current code :) http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5v4cx3om/ - and the reset resets both timer and lap

Comment: So, do you want to say that modifying the DOM with javascript is faster than setting elements directly in HTML?

Comment: For the tiny number of element yes. And you do both which I find clumsier than just have a div per stopwatch